# gem update caused error: undefined method ssl_version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, macos-mojave

I try to update `gem` in my macOS but the following error occurs:

```
$ RUBYOPT= gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `ssl_version=' for #<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext:0x007f8561047638>
Did you mean?  ssl_timeout=
```

The output of `gem update` and `gem install {package_name}` are the same.

The output of `gem env version` or `gem --version` is:

> 3.0.3

The output of `openssl version` is:

> LibreSSL 2.6.5

How can I resolve the issue?

macOS version: 10.14.4

---

Output of `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.4.0 (2016-12-24 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/adv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/adv/.gem/ruby/2.4.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/adv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/adv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/adv/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/adv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/adv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0
     - /Users/adv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/adv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin
     - /Users/adv/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/bin
     - /Users/adv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin
     - /Users/adv/.fastlane/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/adv/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/adv/.rvm/bin
     - /Users/adv/.fastlane/bin
     - /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /Users/adv/.rbenv/shims
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/local/share/dotnet
     - /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
     - /Users/adv/android-sdks/platform-tools
     - /Users/adv/android-sdks/tools
     - /opt/metasploit-framework/bin
     - /opt/metasploit-framework/bin
     - /Users/adv/android-sdks/platform-tools/
     - /Users/adv/android-sdks/tools/
     - /opt/metasploit-framework/bin
     - /opt/metasploit-framework/bin
```

Output of `which gem`:

```
/Users/adv/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/bin/gem
```

Output of `rbenv versions`:

```
  system
* 2.4.1 (set by /Users/adv/.rbenv/version)
```

Output of `ruby -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION"`:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
```

Output of `rvm list`:

```
=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

---

*UPDATE*: After I removed `rvm` and `rbenv` completely (and restarted the Terminal session), I try to execute `gem update` again, here is the result:

```
$ gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating CFPropertyList
Fetching: CFPropertyList-3.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

I think it now uses macOS's system ruby again.

Here are some outputs:

Output of `gem -v`:

> 2.5.2.3

Output of `ruby -v`:

> ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Output of `which gem`:

> /usr/bin/gem

Ouput of `which ruby`:

> /usr/bin/ruby

My aim is to use `gem` without problems (install & update, etc). What should I do next?

Comment: Are you using a Ruby manager like asdf/RVM/rbenv, or are you using system Ruby? (the one built-in to macOS) If you are using system Ruby, don't. Switch to using a Ruby manager.

Comment: rbenv 1.1.1 is installed in system.

Comment: Please post complete `gem env`, `which gem`, `rbenv versions` and `ruby -ropenssl -e "puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_LIBRARY_VERSION"`

Comment: @Vasfed added the output

Comment: @Raptor looks like there's also RVM on the machine (and may conflict), add `rvm list`

Comment: @Vasfed added thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#ssl_version=` appeared in ruby 1.8.7, mac os has 2.3.7 built-in

Just checked on 10.14.2 -

```
require 'openssl'; OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new.ssl_version="TLSv1"
```

works fine even on system ruby, OpenSSL versions are the same as yours.

The only thing left to suspect is rbenv conflict with rvm, because you have both installed, it may mess loaded libraries and ruby compilation. I suggest removing one of them completely (also not forget to start new shell session after this) and reinstall broken ruby.

Comment: I have removed the `rvm` and `rbenv`, and new errors occur. Please see my update above.